# Check input field on mutiple criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that checks if an input field contains a certain criteria.

If the criteria is true, a div with a message will be prompt under the input field.

It works great, but how can I add more cities into the script?

if I do `OR`, for example: `('Amsterdam' || 'London')`, the script won't work.

Can anyone help me please?

**Input Field**

```
<input type="text" name="city" id="address" onblur="check()" value="">
```

**Javascript**

```
function check() {
    var name = document.getElementById('address').value;
    if (name.indexOf('Amsterdam') > -1) {
        $(".message").html("You get a beer!");
        return false;
    }
}

<div class = "message"></div>
```

Comment: You need  `name.indexOf('Amsterdam') > -1 || name.indexOf('London') > -1 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use else if. This way you can have different messages for different criterias. Please see below.

> Syntax

```
if (condition1) {
    block of code to be executed if condition1 is true
} else if (condition2) {
    block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is true
} else {
    block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is false
}
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)

Try this:

```
if (name.indexOf('Amsterdam') > -1) {
  $(".message").html("You get a beer!");
} else if(name.indexOf('London') > -1) {
  $(".message").html("Other message!");
} else {
  $(".message").html("Something else!");
}

return false;
```

If you want to check for multiple criterias and show only one message you can use || (or)

```
if (name.indexOf('Amsterdam') > -1 || name.indexOf('London') > -1) {
  $(".message").html("You get a beer!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (name.indexOf('Amsterdam') > -1 || name.indexOf('London') > -1) {
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not too concerned about the performance, you can use Regex but they are considered slower than `indexOf()`

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
   var name = document.getElementById('address').value;
   if ((/^(Amsterdam|London|Texas|Delhi|Tokyo)$/i).test(name)) {
     $(".message").html("You get a beer!");
     return false;
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="city" id="address" value="">
<button>
  Submit
</button>
<div class="message"></div>
```